Wrap LaTeX conditional into LaTeX3 conditional when condition name is not fixed
I have the following issue. There is a package defining some low-level LaTeX conditionals to represent some switches. For instance, \if_pkg@switchOne, \if_pkg@switchTwo, etc.
Now, using this package in a higher level package that I would like to develop with LaTeX 3, it would be desirable for me to wrap these conditionals in higher level LaTeX3 conditionals. Specifically, I would like to have something that can be used like
\mod_if_pkgswitch:nTF { switch } { true code } { false code }

where switch is some switch name such as switchOne, etc.
Is there a standard way to do this wrapping in LaTeX3?

The expl3 programming environment provides \legacy_if:nTF which takes as argument a switch (without the \if) part:
\documentclass{article}

% package or user defines a switch
\newif\ifwhatever

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkswitch}{mmm}
 {
  \legacy_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\checkswitch{whatever}{true}{false}

\whatevertrue

\checkswitch{whatever}{true}{false}

\end{document}


The first argument to \legacy_if:nTF is “catcode agnostic” (except for active characters, of course). So, if a package defines \if@whatever you can use
\legacy_if:nTF { @whatever } { true } { false }

In pure expl3 code you don't need the \NewDocumentCommand wrapper, of course.

Thanks, I had completely missed the legacy module!
